# Por que o OpenSSH abre apenas quando eu cancelo o comando de push do git?

Tags: git, windows, github, ssh

**Sistema operacional:** Windows 11

**Versão do Git:** 2.32.0.windows.1

Estou tentando fazer um push em um repositório privado no Github usando o Git Bash, mas não acontece nada.

Utilizo a linha de comando `git push origin main`, mas nada acontece. Porém, quando eu pressiono `CTRL + C` abre uma caixa de diálogo do OpenSSH requisitando as credenciais do Github, mas quando insiro e clico em "OK" ele retorna um erro, provavelmente por ter usado o `CTRL + C`.

[image: print da caixa de diálogo do OpenSSH]
[image: print da caixa de diálogo do erro]

Adicionei o repositório remoto normalmente usando `git remote add origin [url de protocolo https]` e também tentei adicionar o utilizando SSH com `git remote set-url origin [url SSH]` e ambas acontecem a mesma coisa.

Tentei também tornar o repositório público, mas também não muda o resultado que descrevi acima.

Gostaria de ajuda para resolver o problema.